# SFMC MobilePush that uses SFDC ContactID as SFMC ContactKey

Tags: mobilepush

I need to configure MobilePush via SFMC but I need the SFDC ContactID to be the SFMC ContactKey

Any suggestions on the best way to pass along the SFDC contactID with the DeviceID to SFMC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will require a lookup to get the `contactId` and then pass it into the MC via the SDK's convenience methods.

You are not the first to want an easier method: please open a Voice of Customer request through your account representative.  The more of those requests they receive, the more likely a feature request gets approved/worked.